# When loading pickle, get import error, "no module named sip"

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, pickle, importerror

I am making a program in python that allows you to change the password. Here is the part that let's you change the password:

```
def done_clicked(self):
    password_filea = open("password.pkl", "r")
    password_check = pickle.load(password_filea)
    username_filea = open("username.pkl", "r")
    username_check = pickle.load(username_filea)


    if self.currpword.text() == password_check and self.reppword.text() == password_check and self.curruser.text() == username_check and self.repuser.text() == username_check:
        password_filea.close()
        username_filea.close()
        password_file = open("password.pkl", "wb")
        username_file = open("username.pkl", "wb")
        pickle.dump(self.newpword.text(), password_file)
        pickle.dump(self.newuser.text(), password_file)
        password_file.close()
        username_file.close()
        easygui.msgbox("Password Changed")
```

And here is the part that loads the username and password to let you sign in:

```
def sign_in_clicked(self):
    password_file = open("password.pkl", "rb")
    password = pickle.load(password_file)
    username_file = open("username.pkl", "rb")
    username = pickle.load(username_file)
    print username
    if self.pword.text() == password and self.username.text() == username:
        MainWindow.show()
        myWindow.hide()
    else:
        easygui.msgbox("Wrong Password!")
    password_file.close()
    username_file.close()
```

When I type in anything, I get this error:

```
    line 154, in sign_in_clicked
password = pickle.load(password_file)
ImportError: No module named sip
```

How do I fix it? Please note that both these functions are under separate classes. Also, it works perfectly when I do it from a separate file, but when it does it from the same file, as it does in the example, it gives me the error. I am importing Cpickle. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/SIP/

Comment: Have you tried doing `pip install SIP`?

Comment: @eyllanesc I'm sorry but I don't understand. I do have SIP installed, yes.

Comment: @Lakshay Garg thanks, but I'm on windows

Comment: You should still be able to use pip on the command prompt, right? If `pip install SIP` does not work, try `python -m pip install SIP`.

Comment: @PMD 
you do not indicate it in your question, are you sure that you have installed sip in the same python that you have installed pickle?

Comment: I doubt that you might have multiple python env or your PATH is incorrect.Use virtual environment(Google:venv) and install all the requirements in the venv and it  may solve your problem.

Comment: @Lakshay Garg I'm sorry but cmd doesn't recognize pip as a command

Comment: @ellyanesc All of my modules are installed in Python27

Comment: @Woody Johnson I think I have the path right. It worked before now.

Comment: Thank you all for your help, but I found the issue. The problem was that I was saving the info to password_file twice.